# How do I always center the container both horizontal and vertical, regardless of content

Tags: html, css, centering

How do I always center the container both horizontal and vertical, regardless of content? Below is a basic example of what I'm trying to do.

Is this method correct, or is there an easier solution to my problem?

```
        <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
        <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en">
        <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
        <title>3 columns</title>


        <style>
        div.container { 
            height: 200px;
            width: 100%;
            margin-left: auto;
            margin-right: auto;
            margin-top: 25%;
            margin-bottom: 20%;  
        }

        div.col {
            float: left;
            width: 25%;

        }
        </style>

        </head>
        <body>

        <div class="container">
            <div class="col" align="center">This is col 1</div>
            <div class="col" align="center">This is col 2</div>
            <div class="col" align="center">This is col3</div>
        </div>


        </body>
        </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
.container {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;

  /*
  Nope =(
  margin-left: -25%;
  margin-top: -25%;
  */

  /* 
  Yep!
  */
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);

  /*
  Not even necessary really. 
  e.g. Height could be left out!
  */
  width: 40%;
  height: 50%;
}
```

Source: http://css-tricks.com/centering-percentage-widthheight-elements/

Note that the `transform` property will need prefixes for some browsers at the time of this writing (`-ms`, `-webkit`).  http://caniuse.com/transforms2d

Comment: Remember to [properly prefix for Webkit browsers](http://caniuse.com/transforms2d).

Comment: Was in the process of that when you left your comment.  ;)

Comment: If IE8 and lower need support I'd go for the [table CSS or pseudo-ghost](http://css-tricks.com/centering-in-the-unknown/) approaches instead. Also, these don't have the issue of pushing the element out of the top of the viewport if it's higher.

Comment: This puts everything in the one column, I need to be able to have 3 centered columns across the page.
col1 | col2 | col3
just like this

Comment: You can style the contents inside the `.container` div however you wish.  You'll just need to add the styling to those `.cols` to make them columnar.

Answer (score 0):

as Niels Keurentjes says...`table-cell` is nice [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AmkDe/)

html:

```
<div class="outer">
    <span class="inner">
        <img src="http://www.google.co.in/trends/resources/2327917647-google-icon.png"/>
    </span>
</div>
<div class="outer">
    <span class="inner">
        <span class="innerinner">blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah</span>
    </span>
</div>
```

css:

```
.outer{
    width:300px;
    height:200px;
    border:1px solid blue;
    display:table;
    text-align:center;
}

.inner{
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
    border:1px solid red;
}
.inner img{
    border:1px solid orange;
}
.innerinner{
    border:1px solid red;
}
```

Comment: Doesn't this put a column above one another? I was after 3 horizontal columns that would be centered in the page.